# Windows Phone: how to change the automated navigation path?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I use TimeSpanPicker in my app. When I pick my time from the timer, it will go back to the initial page automatically (lets say setTime.xaml page). However, I want to change the navigation to another page rather than the setTime.xaml page.

```
enter code here
>> setTime.Xaml.cs Page 

TimeSpanPicker tsp = new TimeSpanPicker();
tsp.ValueChanged += change_Value();

>> Event Handler 

private void change_Value(object sender, RoutedPropertyChanedEventArgs <TimeSPan> e)
{
  //do something
}
```

How can I change its navigation to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Add a event for `ValueChanged`. Write the event handler like this:

```
    private void TimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but actually when I use this method it will go to the page setTimer.xaml and then change to the main page. user can see that it goes to settimer.xaml page.